# EMR bootstrap action to run Hue on Mapr M3

Tags: bigdata, cloudera, hue, mapr

Is there some bootstrap script to get hue running on EMR MapR, unlike setting up using this guide http://doc.mapr.com/display/MapR/Configuring+Hue